# How to write a python program to find the second most repeated word in a given string

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the string as ***Welcome to Datacurators.tech*** and i need to find out second most repeated character in the given string. I need to use only basic python code ( not to use import or def functions). i have the below code but it gives me count of all the characters. Expected output ( e,c,o,a) output could be in any order.

```
stri = "Welcome to Datacurators.tech"
counts={}
for i in stri:
    counts[i]=stri.count(i)
print (counts)
```

Comment: If you wish to count the frequencies then, either you can make a histogram or use a `Counter()`, I guess you don't want the latter.

Comment: Try checking `if i in counts:`. If it is add one to it; if it's not set it to one.

Comment: think about mapping the characters to the occurence counts via a dict and then simply using pythons sorted() function, which requires no includes whatsoever.

Comment: Followed by sorting and depending upon `asec\desc` choose appropriate `1\-2` index from the sorted list\array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary. It loops through the string. If it's not in the `dict`, it creates a key-> value pair. If it's already in the `dict`, it pluses 1 to its frequency.

```py
map = {}
for eachCharacter in stri:
    if eachCharacter not in map:
        map[eachCharacter] = 1
    else:
        map[eachCharacter] += 1
```

This gives you frequency of all characters in the string (including space character, get rid of it if you do not need it). Now we sort this dictionary by its value.

```py
newMap = {k: v for k, v in sorted(map.items(), key = lambda item: item[1])}
```

Then to get the second most frequent, or even the n-th most frequent, use:

```py
list(newMap.keys())[n]
```

And you get the answer.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Note, `list(newMap.keys())` can just be `list(newMap)`

Comment: I disagree with reinventing the wheels, yes more than one in this answer. At least suggest to use a `defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

you can add this block to your code:

```
second_max = sorted(set(counts.values()))[-2] 
# the above line fails if the string length is less than 2 or the unique character count is less than 2, so you need to check for that
seconds = [k for k in counts if counts[k] == second_max] 
print(seconds)
```

Also, notice that for each character in `stri` a `stri.count()` is called which is O(n).
So that means with your algorithm the time complexity is O(n^2) (where n is the string size).

You can do this in O(nlogn):

```
stri = "Welcome to Datacurators.tech"
counts={x:0 for x in stri}
for i in stri: 
    counts[i] += 1 

# then just add the same block from above.
```

As @Pynchia mentioned `defaultdict` or `Counter` would be the way to go, but you wanted no imports.

Note: You can do better than O(nlogn).

Comment: You should convert counts to set first to get the second large count.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to do that.

Comment: You mean you have already covered the case with multiple most frequent chars?@Perplexabot

Comment: I see what you mean now. You are right. Thank you - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, you can first get the second large number and then get all char which count equals to the number:

```
second_large_count = sorted(set(counts.values()),reverse=True)[1] # 1 means second (large) item

second_large_char_set = {k for k,v in counts.items() if v ==second_large_count}

print(second_large_char_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. find the character frequency
2. sort the dictionary by keys
3. then print the 2nd last value of it.

```py
str1 = 'visheshsahu'

dict = {}

for n in str1:

        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
r = sorted(dict.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])

print(r[-2])
```